# How to simulate mouse position and mouse offset properties during testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working on a web game where a user is given an image and is tasked with finding someone or something in the image. The app works by checking to see if the user clicked the correct position on the image and validating if the mouse offsetX and mouse offsetY fall into a range.

The problem is that I'm having trouble writing a test for such a function because I don't know how to simulate mouse offsets when clicking on a position. Here's what I'm currently doing

```
it("validates if the user clicked on the correct spot", async () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Game imgData={gameImgData} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  const startBtn = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /start/i });
  await user.click(startBtn);
  const gameImg = screen.getByAltText("game-screen");
  await user.click(gameImg);
  expect(screen.getByText("You win!")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This is a simplified version of the game component that's being tested.

```
function Game(image){
  const checkVictory = (e) => {
    if (e.offsetX === 400) {
      console.log("You win!")
    }
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <img src={image.src} alt="game-screen" onClick={checkVictory} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Previously, I tried to make a fake mouseEvent with offset properties, and I tried to use `fireEvent(gameImg, fakeMouseEvent)` but that didn't work either (Running fireEvent doesn't even seem to call the function). The MouseEvent constructor doesn't allow me to set offsetX and offsetY as far as I can tell either.

Is there a good way to simulate mouse offsets in the react testing library?

Comment: Can you show the code of the `Game` component? How did you use the `offsetX` and `offsetY`?

Comment: @LinDu I added a simplified version of the game component. I'm using offsetX and offsetY to find out where on the image a user has clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The event handlers will be passed instances of [SyntheticEvent](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events), the `SyntheticEvent` does not have the `offsetX` property, you should access the `offsetX` property from `nativeEvent`.

E.g.

`Game.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";

export function Game(props) {
  const checkVictory = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.offsetX === 400) {
      console.log('You win!');
    }
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <img src={props.src} alt="game-screen" onClick={checkVictory} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

`Game.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Game } from './Game';
import React from 'react';

describe('76106321', () => {
  it('validates if the user clicked on the correct spot', async () => {
    render(<Game src="" />);
    const gameImg = screen.getByAltText('game-screen');
    const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });

    Object.defineProperty(event, 'offsetX', { value: 400 });
    fireEvent(gameImg, event);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76106321/Game.test.tsx (6.51 s)
  76106321
    ✓ validates if the user clicked on the correct spot (31 ms)

  console.log
    You win!

      at checkVictory (stackoverflow/76106321/Game.tsx:6:15)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.786 s, estimated 7 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution but offsetX is still coming up as undefined. Using nativeEvent does work if I toy with the app in the browser. But if I try to run a test, it still fails anyway.

Comment: @Alphatron Can you post a new question and reproduce your issue?